# No response from second button

Tags: java, swt

I am making a map over the highest mountains in Europe. I have set up the background in a Label in order to make the buttons invisible:[edit full code]

```
package topOfEurope;
//Importing packages
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;
import org.eclipse.wb.swt.SWTResourceManager;
import org.eclipse.swt.*;

public class display {
    public static String[] country = {"Albania","Andorra","Austria", "Azerbaijan","Belarus","Belgium","Bosnia and Herzegovina",
        "Bulgaria","Croatia","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Estonia","Finland","France","Georgia",
        "Germany","Greece","Hungary","Iceland","Ireland","Italy","Kosovo","Latvia","Liechtenstein","Lithuania",
        "Luxembourg","Macedonia","Malta","Moldova","Monaco","Montenegro","Netherlands","Norway","Poland",
        "Portugal","Romania","Russia","San Merino","Serbia","Slovakia","Slovenia","Spain","Sweden","Switzerland",
        "Turkey","Ukraine","United Kingdom","Vatican City"};
    public static String[] highestPoint = {"Mount Korab","Coma Pedrosa","Großglockner","Bazardüzü","Dzyarzhynskaya Hara","Signal de Botrange",
        "Maglić","Musala","Dinara","Mount Olympus (Cyprus)","Sněžka","Møllehøj","Suur Munamägi","Halti","Mont Blanc","Shkhara",
        "Zugspitze","Mount Olympus","Kékes","Hvannadalshnúkur","Carrauntoohil","Monte Bianco","Djeravica/Great Rudoka",
        "Gaizinkalns","Vorder Grauspitz","Aukštojas Hill","Kneiff","Mount Korab","Ta' Dmejrek","Bălăneşti","Chemin des Révoires",
        "Zla Kolata","Vaalserberg","Galdhøpiggen","Mount Rysy","Mount Pico","Moldoveanu Peak","Mount Elbrus","Monte Titano",
        "Midžor","Gerlachovský štít","Triglav","Mulhacén","Kebnekaise","Monte Rosa","Mahya Dağı","Hoverla","Ben Nevis",
        "unnamed location"};
    public static String[] MAMSL = {"2764","2942","3798","4466","345","694","2386","2925","1831","1952","1603","171","318","1324","4810","5201",
        "2962","2919","1014","2110","1041","4810","2656","311","2599","294","560","2764","253","430","163","2534","321","2469",
        "2499","2351","2544","5642","749","2169","2655","2864","3479","2104","4634","1031","2061","1344","75"};
    protected Shell shell;
    public Button _2;
    private Label txtCountry;
    private Label txtHighestMountain;
    private Label txtMeters;
    private Label lblNewLabel;
    private Button button;
    private Button _3;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            display window = new display();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();}}
    /**
     * Open the window.
     */
    public void open() {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }}}
    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */


    private SelectionListener getCountrySelectionListener(final String country, final String MAMSL, final String highestPoint) {
        return new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                try{
                txtCountry = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
                txtCountry.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
                txtCountry.setText("Country: \r\n" + country);
                txtCountry.setBounds(1082, 0, 349, 81);
                txtCountry.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Lucida Grande", 20, SWT.BOLD));

                txtHighestMountain = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
                txtHighestMountain.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
                txtHighestMountain.setText("Highest Mountain: \r\n" + highestPoint);
                txtHighestMountain.setBounds(1082, 81, 349, 81);
                txtHighestMountain.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Lucida Grande", 20, SWT.BOLD));

                txtMeters = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
                txtMeters.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
                txtMeters.setText("Meters above sea level: \r\n" + MAMSL);
                txtMeters.setBounds(1082, 159, 349, 81);
                txtMeters.setFont(SWTResourceManager.getFont("Lucida Grande", 20, SWT.BOLD));
                }
                catch(Exception exc) {
                    MessageDialog.openError(shell,"Error","anuallyInvestedMoney amount");
                    return;
                }
}};}    

    protected void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell();
        shell.setImage(null);
        shell.setSize(1440, 899);
        shell.setText("List of highest points of European countries");

        //testing
        System.out.println(getInfo.getInfo3());

        //Setting background image
        //shell.setBackgroundImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("/Users/Hadle/Downloads/europe_topography_map_en.jpg"));
        Label lblNewLabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        lblNewLabel.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("/Users/Hadle/Downloads/europe_topography_map_en.jpg"));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(-206, -170, 1473, 1198);

        //Creating buttons

        Button _1 = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        _1.setBounds(532, 695, 23, 50);
        _1.setText("1");

        _2 = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        _2.setBounds(166, 655, 94, 28);
        _2.setText("2");

        _3 = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        _3.setBounds(410, 552, 67, 38);
        _3.setText("New Button");

        //Creating button array
        Button[] btnArr = new Button[] {
                _1, _2, _3
            };

        //Assigning values to buttons
        for(int i = 0; i < btnArr.length; i++) {
            btnArr[i].addSelectionListener(getCountrySelectionListener(country[i],MAMSL[i],highestPoint[i]));
        } } }
```

It works fine when I run the program and click on one button to view information about the highest mountain in one country. However when I want to click on another country, the code does not respond, but is stuck with the information from the last button. Therefore I am looking for suggestions to changes, so that I can click on many buttons and it will show all the different countries without becoming stuck.

For assigning values to the buttons I use the following code:

```
    //Creating button array
    Button[] btnArr = new Button[] {
            _1, _2
        };

    //Assigning values to buttons
    for(int i = 0; i < btnArr.length; i++) {
        btnArr[i].addSelectionListener(getCountrySelectionListener(country[i],MAMSL[i],highestPoint[i]));
```

Cheers

Comment: What is `SWTResourceManager`?

Comment: It is a UI tool for creating application windows.

Comment: do you need to give it a unique "id"?

Comment: I am using the following code: //Creating button array
  Button[] btnArr = new Button[] {
       _1, _2
   };
  
  //Assigning values to buttons
  for(int i = 0; i < btnArr.length; i++) {
      btnArr[i].addSelectionListener(getCountrySelectionListener(country[i],MAMSL[i],highestPoint[i]));
  }

Comment: @HRS non formatted code in comment -bad idea. Additional code as edit to the question - good idea

Comment: Thanks mate, now it is up in the main question.

Comment: What does `getCountrySelectionListener` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just didn't created the button _2 right.

`//wrong
_2 = new Button();
//right
Button _2 = new Button();`

I am sorry if that is wrong. I don't understand your code in many ways.
You propably used JButton, because there is no .setText or new Button() with two parameters.

An other problem could be,that you didn't set the Layout.
`frame.setLayout(null);`

Otherwise I would need the whole code.

Cheers

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I am pretty sure I got the button right, because I get the answer up if I choose the country as my first choice, but then it freezes with that country´s details. How do you suppose I should implement the setLayout? I have added the full code by the way.

Comment: You answer looks like it is for Swing, the question is about SWT.